# Jetpack Compose - MotionLayout with scrollableView

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-nestedscrollview, android-motionlayout

I have a Compose `MotionLayout` with :

- a title at the middle of the screen first
- a bellow content which can be a `LazyColumn` or a `Column` with `verticalScroll()`

When I `dragUp` the content, the title must go to the top of the screen (it works) and the content must remain bellow (it works too).

I use `NestedScrollConnection` to detect when there is a `DragUp` on my `List` and apply it to my `swipeableState` (`swipeableState.performDrag(...)`).

The problem is that my `LazyColumn`/`scrollable` column scrolls inside itself during the `MotionLayout` top animation.
I do not remember in XML I had this issue.

How to handle it?